# Where to buy an SR Latch

Tags: components, buying

I am looking for a simple SR Latch. I'm new to electronics though and just doing a hobby project/teaching myself. Are SR Latches sold (I'm hoping to avoid building mine because I actually need at least 5) and if so where can I buy them (Radio Shack?) and what do I ask for? I link to a site with a part number would help too.

Per the comments. I have called Radio Shack and they said they didn't have them. The local big electronics store could only help me if I had a part number. I don't know if they actually can't help me or if I just don't know what to ask for. Is my best option just building them? I was kind of hoping I could just buy a small self contained item that was a SR Latch. If I were to wire them myself they would take up significantly more space.

Comment: This question will likely not be considered appropriate for the site, but the quick answer is, "74LS279" is a common part number for a quad SR-latch IC. And findchips.com is a site that lets you search multiple electronic components distributors for any part number you like.

Comment: @ThePhoton: I agree with the assessment of the question as is, but with a few edits it could be a well-worded question. My first thought was, "Of course there's a quad RS latch available", but it took me quite a while to find one, and none of the 3 parts (LS279, CD4043/4044) are likely to be easily available except by mail order.

Comment: @JasonS, For me, TI's datasheet for LS279 came up in the top 5 Google results when I searched for "SR-latch". I had to look at a couple more links to remind myself that it only takes 2 NAND or NOR gates to construct an SR-latch.

Comment: @William: This and other stackexchange sites are more welcoming to questions that show an appearance of more effort on your part; if you said "I tried googling for SR latch but couldn't find a part number", and didn't say "link to a site with a part number would help too" (makes it sound like you're expecting us to do your work for you), I think your question would be better received.

Comment: @ThePhoton: When I google "RS latch" (which I was what I was taught it was called), I get the Wikipedia page on flip-flops as the first result, which nowhere mentions the 279, and a number of diagrams of the standard pedagogical NAND and NOR gate implementation. (If I recall correctly, latches and flip-flops can have metastability issues if you try to naively construct them from gates.) It took me several minutes of searching to find the logic gate numbers for RS latches, and that's for someone who's fairly familiar with manufacturers' and vendors' websites.

Comment: ....and when I google "SR-latch", I don't get TI's datasheet in the top five results. Now that Google uses online identity and location as search inputs, it's no longer safe to assume that everyone else gets the same Google results as you do.

Comment: @JasonS, RE " it's no longer safe to assume that everyone else gets the same Google results as you do." Absolutely right, that's why I included the caveat "for me". ... Also, re-checking my browser history, the search term I used was "ti SR latch".

Comment: @JasonS, RE metastability, I don't see any reason for the circuit to be metastable when built from two gates (but maybe I'm missing something). There is an inherent metastable state if R & S are tied together and switched from 1 to 0, which should occur whether the latch is integrated or built from parts. An integrated part could be specifically designed to resolve the metastability, I guess.

Comment: @Photon: "ti SR latch" -- aha, I get a 279 as well in my results. Sounds like this site could use a FAQ entry for online parts searching (when you don't know a part #), since it's nontrivial.

Comment: @JasonS I apologize if it seems like I didn't make an effort but Radio Shack couldn't help me and the guy at the specialty electronics store in my area didn't know anything and could only help if I had a part number. All I found when searching were the quad switches and I don't know enough about electronics to even know if I'm asking the correct questions. Hence the question here.

Comment: RE edits, How many do you need? If you have to wire it from gates it may not be too bad. Quad NAND or quad NOR is a common configuration, which gives you two SR-latches from a single IC.

Comment: @ThePhoton I think I'm going to need at least 5 running on momentary press switches; and when I press a switch it needs to cancel all the other ones at the same time. So the S trigger will be the switch for the current latch and the R trigger will be the switch for any other latch.

Comment: One reason there's so few part numbers for an SR-latch is that its very rare that this part is really the best solution to your problem...The answer to your other question shows one way to solve the problem with 3 ICs and a few passives, and *no* SR-latches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RS latches have several parts in the industry-standard 7400 and CD4000 series, all of which are quad packages in old logic families:

- [74LS279](http://www.ti.com/product/sn74ls279a)
- [CD4043](http://www.ti.com/product/cd4043b)
- [CD4044](http://www.ti.com/product/cd4044b)

Another alternative, with two parts in a package rather than 4, but more available in modern logic families (read: lower-voltages) would be to use a 74xx74 dual D flip-flop as an R-S latch by grounding its data and clock inputs, and using the PRE and CLR inputs as S and R inputs, respectively. In this case, I'd start with a [74HC74](http://www.ti.com/product/sn74hc74).

Comment: Thanks for the information. I was hoping to be able to just buy a little latch. For some reason having to buy a quad seems not right and I need 5 anyway so I would have to get two of them. Arg.

Comment: @William, you can build a latch with transistors. Jason, could you expand on why I would pick 74LA279 over a CD4043? That is what makes this a serious answer instead of links to suppliers.

Comment: I probably wouldn't pick either; LS279 is faster but CD40xx works with higher-voltage circuits, and neither work with supplies under 4.5V. I'd use the hc74 instead unless I were pressed for space and could get by with one of the others.

Comment: @JasonS, I meant to say, why not take this as a chance to explain why you would pick each family and why they are separate chips. Make it a more thorough answer.

Comment: CD4000 logic works on anything from 3V-15V. Can't beat being able to run directly from a coin cell to a car battery with no regulation.

Comment: Good point, but I wouldn't run directly on a car battery due to its large surge voltages.

Answer (score 0):

you can make it using two NANAD or two NOR gates.You have no need two buy IV for S-R latch even.

Comment: I know I could build one. But I need a minimum of 4 so if I was going to build one I would have to build 4 of them. This would take a lot more space than some pre-packaged version and I will probably only have a few square inches of space to put them in.

Comment: @William, space requirements are useful for your design.

Answer (score -3):

[Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/)
[Newark](http://www.newark.com/)
[Mouser](http://cn.mouser.com/Home.aspx)
[Future Electronics](http://www.futureelectronics.com/WebsiteLanding.aspx)
[Spark Fun](http://www.sparkfun.com/)

Comment: I didn't "-1" you, but I agree with the sentiment. It seems like the OP is asking for more help in parts selection than in vendor selection.

Comment: If you're going to include SparkFun, may as well include Jameco too: http://www.jameco.com/ . Historically they had awful prices, but checking them out today they beat out the big distributors on several hobbyist-friendly parts (74ls04 in DIP, 1n4004, etc.). These were their own featured parts so YMMV.