# Stacked MOSFETs

Tags: mosfet

Will the following scheme work if one of the lockout gates are energized?  Or another way of putting it, can the normal operation of a MOSFET be achieved by the connection and disconnection of the source, or the drain for that matter, while the gate is energized?

[image: Stacked MOSFETs]

I am also looking for a chart with the 4 basic wiring scenarios of N-Enhancement, N-depletion, P-Enhancement, AND P-Depletion.  I could probably figure it out, but why reinvent the wheel?  Does anyone know of one?

Thanks.

Here is what seems to be the best alternative:
[image]

All the FET devices are identical and avoid the hard to find, expensive types. None have floating gates, and the double load on the 555s, and the additional load on the PS is minimal.

Thank you everybody.

Comment: Why not use a [wired logic gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_logic_connection) with diodes, that seems much cheaper and simpler.

Comment: Floating gates are going to lead to undefined results. All three of those gates can float, depending on the switch state.

Comment: The depletion mode ones are normally closed style, you apply voltage at the gate to turn them off. The act kind of like P channel MOSFET in that case. Energizing the gates of those two lockout ones WILL open them and cut off current to the load after them. As mentioned though, put pulldown resistors to ground at each gate to ensure no floating charge

Comment: Your question is good if the goal is to better understand MOSFET usage. But we may also suggest a better topology to actualy solve your problem. But here it's not clear, at least to me, what is the final behavior you want to achieve with your buttons and the coil.

Comment: Wired logic gate with diodes--interesting possibility.

Comment: Wired logic gate with diodes--interesting possibility. Floating gates seem intuitively bad to me--they could easily be referenced to ground with a resistors.  One of the goals is to better understand MOSFETs.  The other goal is to lockout the enhancement mode device at the bottom, which is controlled by a 555 wired for flip-flop from a momentary contact.  But there are two scenarios where energizing the coil would not be allowed, which led to the depletion device idea.

Comment: Depletion mode MOSFET are expensive and have terrible R_on characteristics on comparison to standard/similar style enhancement mode components. A better of two evils for those pass elements is perhaps P channel MOSFETs that are pulled to ground by some TTL logic through standard NPN transistors

Comment: "A better of two evils for those pass elements is perhaps P channel MOSFETs that are pulled to ground by some TTL logic through standard NPN transistors." I was tempted to use electromechanical, low signal relays, but I am running out of board space, and the delay may be a problem, although at 110% nominal coil votage, the make/break speeds approach optical devices with the ones I am using.

Comment: "P-channel MOSFETs.."  Enhancement mode I presume.  I really need a chart, perhaps I will start on one.

Comment: Can you define "work" as used in the first sentence of the question? It's not clear what the expected behaviour is.

Comment: @user40155 depending on the current for this relay of yours, you can use VERY small mosfets and NPN transitors. In fact, a dual package NPN transistor can be in a nice small SOT363 6-pin layout. The MOSFET can be found in low (1-3A) power ratings in similarly small (SOT23, SOIC8 , etc) packages.

Comment: @JohnU"Can you define 'work' as used in the first sentence of the question?" That the depletion MOSFETS would open the circuit, and conduct with a gate voltage below threshold, and that the enhancement device would turn on and off without being molested by the operation of either of the depletion devices.

Comment: @KyranF:  Coil current is only 12mA. Does the scheme you have in mind utilize both MOSFETs and BJTs?

Comment: @jippie:  Looks like the wired diode logic is the best alternative for this application, when considering the complexity level and the source of the signals, which I did not include before.

Comment: @user40155  yes it seems some pre-logic before turn off the pass element is a good way to reduce the current-bearing series load components. The coil being only 12mA is very low, surely you mean 120mA?

Comment: @KyranF: Well, the timers were already there to stay. They are used for a momentary N.O. switch control, touch on, touch off. The sheet says 11.7mA.  It is a low-signal relay Panasonic TX2-12V-1. In my application, they are used to switch audio signals in a preamp. http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/316/tx-catalog-16210.pdf  Thank you for the heads up anyway.

Comment: @user40155 yeah the timers are okay for a one-shot style pulse to turn off the relay - seems like your setup will work fine then. Just make sure all MOSFETs chosen in your designs have the correct voltage thresholds (logic level!), for example the output of the OR gate and FET2's Vgs threshold should be quite low (1-2V) for power efficient and fast action.

Comment: oh and don't forget pull-down resistors on the gates of your FETs, as when the OR gate goes low, there is nothing to sink current out of the Gate and therefore actually turn the FET off.

Comment: @KyranF:  Wow, thanks, I would have never thought of a sink for the gate!  The rest of them actually have dividers but I didn't show them to keep it simple. You have saved me hours of aggravation! The 2N7000 has a Vgs(th) of 2.1-3v., turns on in 10ns, good for 200mA--500mA inrush, and comes in the beloved TO-92 case. A good one is $0.42 in small qty.

Comment: @KyranF:  I forgot to mention the 555s are not "one shot" they are latching on-off.

Comment: @user40155 i guess you are stuck with the 555s, but that's not very normal operation for them.. an SR Latch or D-flipflop IC should be used instead. Seems strange, but you are modifying an existing design/interface so I guess you are stuck. And Vgs(th) of 2.1-3V, if you are using a 3.3V voltage at FET2 then it might only "just" turn on and still be in the linear region of resistance. I guess for all this low power switching it should be okay, just that if you don't get the R_On resistance low enough, it might not pull FET3 to ground good enough

Comment: @KyranF I am not stuck with the 555, but at the time it satisfied the characteristic of maintaining its state with the N.O. momentary switch held, i.e, output low, switch closed,  555 output goes high and stays there (even if the switch is held closed) until the switch is opened and closed again, which would make the output low.  Same in reverse.  I looked at the D-flipflop hastily and saw something that would not work, or I didn't like, so I started on the 555 and finally got it to work flawlessly.  It has to work every time and cannot change states by itself for any reason whatsoever.

Comment: with a SR-Latch, the button input would go to the S pin, which "sets" it. Completely seperate is the "R" pin which "resets" the state, putting the output low. That is a robust and with a series resistor and small capacitor to ground on each input to give some noise immunity (debounce, basically) you would have the same thing

Comment: @user40155 check out this question's verified answer [Where to buy RS Latch](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/25811/where-to-buy-an-sr-latch)

Comment: @KyranF Only one input: a momentary pushbutton. This did not work: http://www.mosaic-industries.com/embedded-systems/_detail/microcontroller-projects/electronic-circuits/push-button-switch-turn-on/latching-high-side-push-on-push-off-toggle-switch-circuit.png?id=microcontroller-projects:electronic-circuits:push-button-switch-turn-on:latching-toggle-power-switch  Even the 555 scheme needed some fiddling with cap and resistor values.  I started with "555 as flip flop" http://www.talkingelectronics.com/projects/555/Page3-555.html Most of the schemes fail to detail switch action and its effects.

Comment: So really you just want a toggle?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. One, normally open contact switch for input control, and when switch is made and held closed, the device transfers to the next state and stays there.  To change states again, the switch must be opened and then closed again.  Only about 1 millisecond of hysteresis is permitted.  In other words, the "on delay" so to speak, has to be almost instantaneous in both directions.  And any scheme that satisfies these attributes must be inherently bounceless; that is why that attribute was not specified.

Think of silent, two position snap switch, like a musical instrument stomp box switch except without the noise. I neither like the noise, nor do I wish to raise my leg.  I haven't seen any on the market, probably because of the inherent unreliability. The balance between very short delay and bouncelessness has to be negotiated.  A dirty or unreliable contact could cause problems, as would a lazy foot.

(I was just able to sign in with my username.  I had asked the question under temp user.)